# Is $\left(e^y\right)y' + \left(e^y\right)y + \left(e^y\right)x = 0$ a linear ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We all know that any linear first order ODE can be represented in this form :
$$
a(x)y' + b(x)y + e(x) = 0
$$
That is to say that: 
$$
Equation 1:                   \left(e^y\right)y' + \left(e^y\right)y +  \left(e^y\right)x = 0
$$
is not linear?

Equation 1 is clearly not in the "$a(x)y' + b(x)y + e(x) = 0$" form but it acts like a linear first order ODE. So, is differential equation 1 considered linear or not?

Comment: How did you get your second equation?

Comment: What do you mean ? I forgot to place e^y multiplying x, now its fixed.

Comment: It's obviously not linear because you can't write $e^{y(x)}$ in terms of $x$ alone. You need to know $y$ which is precisely what you're solving for... But since you can factor by $e^y$ and $e^{y(x)}\not= 0, \forall x$, your equation is equivalent to a linear equation.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I apologize, I normally take linear to mean linear homogeneous.

Your ODE $(e^y)y' + (e^y)y + (e^y)x = 0$ is linear, but not homogeneous. The only way for an ODE to be linear and homogeneous is if one can rewrite it such that, in each term, the dependent variable appears (in your case, $y$) exactly once as a derivative term that isn't modified by any higher powers or other functions. In your case, even after you divide by $e^y$, your equation has an $x$ term that makes it not homogeneous, but it makes it linear in the sense that you have defined.

More precisely, an ODE is an $n$th-order linear equation if
$$ c_n(x) y^{(n)} + c_{n-1} y^{(n-1)} + \ldots + c_1 y' + c_0 y + f(x) = 0,$$

where if $f(x) \equiv 0$, then the equation is also homogeneous. Alternatively, you can test whether an ODE is a linear homogeneous by asking yourself the following: if $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$ are both solutions to the ODE, will $Ay_1 + By_2$ be a solution for any numbers $A,B$? If yes, then the equation is linear homogeneous, and other the equation is not.

Comment: I edited the ODE, check again please.And also, wouldnt the independent variable be x and the dependent variable be y in my ODE?

Comment: You're right, sorry, I meant dependent.

Comment: Yes, linear nonhomogeneous is slightly sloppy terminology. I would say affine. But I would be alone. So I don't say it.

Comment: @julien why linear inhomogeneous ODE is sloppy?

Comment: @Kaster Because it is not linear in $y$.

Comment: @Christopher Isn't the requirement for something to be linear to have the additivity/superposition property you mentioned ( given y1,y2 solution, Ay1 + By2 is also a solution ) ? Every non-homogeneous ODE won't hold the superposition property hence won't be linear.I think julien is right when he says it should called affine.

Comment: Linearity of ODE is a property of differential operator on LHS. If for the equation $Ly=0$ it's true that $L(y_1+y_2) = L(y_1)+L(y_2)$ then that differential operator is linear. The fact that for homogeneous ODE all solutions are span of basis solutions is a consequence of Linearity of the $L$, which doesn't hold for inhomogeneous ODE, but it has nothing to do with linearity of differential operator, hence I believe with terminology.

Comment: This sounds like a semantics question, for what it's worth.

Comment: Kaster, you said we need a homogeneous ODE to have a linear differential operator ?

Comment: @nerdy no, I said linear homogeneous and inhomogeneous ODEs are called "Linear" because of the linearity of differential operator that's responsible for the ODE. If you want to check linearity of your equation – check linearity of that operator, i.e. the identity $L(y_1+y_2) = L(y_1)+L(y_2)$

Comment: Hey, guys. Everybody knows what this means and everything is fine. Kaster, you don't need to teach us what the associated differential operator is...please... Linear is fine. I use the terminology and I live with it very well. Even if it's actually affine. Like a linear system $AX=B$ is affine when $B\neq 0$. I mean, its solution set. Kaster, yes, I know, a matrix is a linear operator.